# Check active Transactions within a Xodus environment?

Tags: java, database, xodus

What's the way to check if there are active transactions in a Xodus Environment?

So if you have this:

`Environment environment = environmentCache.get(databasePath);`

How do you get to know if there are active transactions in this environment?

Comment: How are you going to use such information?

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov in order to terminate the Java process that is locking the environment, so before terminating it the program will first check if there current active transactions then if there are no more transactions (after waiting) then it can safely terminate the process by ID

Comment: why not just close the Environment?

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov not possible, the program that will terminate the process that holds the lock the the environment is different, meaning two different processes. So this "Xodus" process that holds the environment, will expose a remote method that in turn returns true/false for a method `isTransactionActive()` method, if this return false, the other process can then safely terminate the "Xodus" process. And by remote I mean RMI.

Comment: How would you resolve a race condition - a new transaction can start after your exposed method returned the fact that there are no active transactions? Why not just expose a method that closes the environment?

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov Hmmm, yeah that makes more sense, never thought of that actually. If you can put this into an answer then I would accept it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To safely close Environment under load, use the following code:

```
// on init stage:
env.getEnvironmentConfig().setEnvCloseForcedly(true);

// method that closes environment:
env.executeTransactionSafeTask(() -> {
    env.executeInExclusiveTransaction(t -> {
        env.close();
    });
});
```

The code is extracted as a [test](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/environment/src/test/java/jetbrains/exodus/env/TransactionTest.java#L528). This way of closing Environment is not immediate, it waits until currently started transactions finish and then closes the environment in an exclusive transaction in order to make sure that no other writing transaction can be started in parallel. There still can be parallel read-only transactions, but they obviously can be ignored.

Expose the code as a remote method to control Environment remotely. After calling the method, remote end can immediately try to open Environment above the same location with reasonably long lock timeout (`EnvironmentConfig.setLogLockTimeout(..)`), say, 1 minute.